# Fill matrixA into matrixB, then add new element to each array inside matrixB

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to fill matrixA into matrixB, then add new element to each array inside matrixB.

`let number = 100;`

```
matrixA = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4]
];
```

```
matrixB = [
    [1, 2, 100],
    [3, 4, 100]
];
```

At this moment i have this code:

```
for (let n in matrixB){
    matrixB[n] = matrixA.slice();
}
```

But Im having issues adding the "number = 100"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the following code.

```js
const matrixA = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4]
];
const number = 100;
const matrixB = matrixA.map(arr => [...arr, number]);
console.log(matrixB);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```js
console.time('test');
const matrixA = [[1, 2], [3, 4]], matrixB = [];
for(let a of matrixA){
  matrixB.push([...a, 100]);
}
console.log(matrixA); console.log(matrixB); console.timeEnd('test');
```

Here's another

```js
console.time('test');
const matrixA = [[1, 2], [3, 4]], matrixB = matrixA.map(a=>[...a, 100]);
console.log(matrixA); console.log(matrixB); console.timeEnd('test');
```